# What does "pop & drag" mean in low light photography?

Tags: flash, terminology, low-light, shutter

I came cross this term "Pop & Drag" being used in low light setting. What does that mean?

Is it the same as term as "dragging the shutter"?

Can anyone please show some examples of "Pop & Drag" photography?

Answer (score 5):

I have not heard that term used before, but it obviously refers to dragging the shutter, and popping a bit of flash.  The idea is to adjust the shutter to control the ambient exposure.

Because the flash duration is so short, whether the camera shutter speed is 1/200th or 1/30th doesn't affect the flash exposure.  But reducing the shutter speed makes a big difference in the background which is not lit by the flash.

Here is a shot where I set the shutter speed was 1/15th, in order to allow for some motion blur, then a pop of flash to freeze the action.  Not the best example since a lot of flash did light the background in this case.

For a more classic example, see this from Neil van Niekerk - [Dragging the Shutter](http://neilvn.com/tangents/flash-photography-techniques/3-dragging-the-shutter/)

[image: Dragging the Shutter]

Comment: +1. But, a pedantic note: on some cameras, 1/200th is shorter than the sync speed.

Comment: Nice shot! filler...